# Cloudflare blocks VB NET Web Requests

Tags: vb.net, cloudflare

I'm trying to send a request and retrive an information from the website with my program using HttpWebRequest in VB .NET.

The problem is that since the website use Cloudflare, my requests returns an 503 Server Unavailable error.

What can i do to make the web requests works with Cloudflare?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

My advice is you whitelist the IP of the server hosting the VB.NET code at a CloudFlare level. To do this, select your site in the CloudFlare admin panel, select Firewall > IP Firewall. Then simply whitelist your IP under Access Rules by adding it there (make sure to select whitelist instead of block).